# Why does swipe up on a UITableView run the cellForRowAt function each time?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that when the function `cellForRowAt` is called some calculations are being made. This all works great until I found out that when I swipe up on the `tableview`, the `cellForRowAt` function is called each time. Is this a bug in iOS 11 (GM) or something that should be happening? If this is default behavior is it possible to deactivate the swipe up gesture?

Comment: `cellForRowAt` is called whenever a new cell is to appear, which typically happens when the tableview is being scrolled upwards. I would assume that this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: you need to implement the prepareForReuse method of your custom cell and reset all the calculations you do in your cellForRowAt method

Comment: I think it is expected behaviour

Comment: This is normal behavior of tableview and you should make your calculations in `cellforrow` with keep this thing in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use

```
dequeueReusableCell
```

in `cellForRowAt`.`UITableView` redraw cells that not display on screen every time when you swipe up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we scroll down or up `cellForRowAt` will be called due to intraction and change in behaviour of `UITableView` and whwn  changes happend then cell has to redesign its self.